Intuition of Ordinal Number
I am learning the concept of ordinal numbers.
In the book of Set Theory and Metric Spaces by I. Kaplansky (Sec. 3.2, pg. 55), the author states

We attach to every well-ordered set an ordinal number; two well-ordered sets are awarded the same ordinal number if and only if they are order-isomorphic.

In Wiki, it states that

A natural number (which, in this context, includes the number 0) can be used for two purposes: to describe the size of a set, or to describe the position of an element in a sequence. When restricted to finite sets, these two concepts coincide. When dealing with infinite sets, however, one has to distinguish between the notion of size, which leads to cardinal numbers, and the notion of position, which leads to the ordinal numbers described here.

My first question is then: according to Wiki, an ordinal number should describe the position of an element in a set. Then why the ordinal number is attached to a set? Shouldn't it be attached to an element of a set?
Moreover, I am also confused by the meaning of "set A has a larger ordinal than set B". I mean, for cardinal numbers, I understand that set A has a larger cardinal than B generally means A has a larger size than B. For example, $A=\{0,1,2\}$ and $B=\{0\}$. But how can we say the "position" or the "ordering" of A is larger than that of B?
It will be appreciated if you can explain with some concrete examples. I have checked the answers here and here, but found no help.

One of the first surprises for a newcomer in set theory is that we can establish a bijection from the set of the natural numbers to , say , the set of the prime numbers although the prime numbers are a proper subset of the natural numbers. In the finite case , this cannot happen.

To deal with infinite "numbers" , we need a concept beyond the natural numbers (they are always finite). The set theory is powerful enough to deal with countable infinities. It can speak of the "set of the natural numbers" and define this set as an object , namely $\omega$ , the first ordinal number larger than every natural number. But it does not have a "position" , there is no largest object (natural number) smaller than $\omega$.

Compare the number of eggs in a box: the cardinal number, with the number of a building in a street: the ordinal number. In the first case the eggs are all the same and there is no "first" egg, while in the second there is the first building, the third, and so on.

In Kaplansky note that an ordinal is not assigned to any random set.  it is only assigned to a well ordered set.

The ordinal of an element $a$ in a well-ordered set $(W,<)$ (as described in your Wiki quote) is the ordinal of the well-ordered subset ${x\in W:x<a}$ (as described in your Kaplansky quote).

Have you checked the comments in this question? The question addresses about natural numbers, but some replies are relevant to your question.

There are a few results and definitions which might be helpful to know about, when trying to understand Ordinals.
I won't be proving these results, but they are usually proven in any Introduction to Axiomatic Set Theory Textbook. ( Enderton,Halmos etc..)
Theorem:
Every Well-Ordering (X,R) is Isomorphic to a unique ordinal. We call such an ordinal the type(X,R).
Definition (Predecessor)
Let (X,R) be a well-order. Let x$\in$X, then
pred(x,X,R) = {y$\in$X| (y,x)$\in$R}
Definition: (Initial Segment of a well-order)
An initial segment of a well-order (X,R) is
(pred(x,X,R),R) for some x$\in$X
If pred(x,X,R) $\neq$ X, such an initial segment is called a proper initial segment.
Theorem: No Well-Order is isomorphic to any of its proper initial segments.
We also have that (pred(x,X,R),R) is a well-order, so by our earlier theorem is is isomorphic to some ordinal. Even more, it is known that the ordinal it is isomorphic to is an element of the ordinal that (X,R) is isomorphic to.
That is the sense in which Ordinals "measure" the length of well-orderings.
We can think of well-orders as lines, and ordinals measure the length of the line, initial segments of the line, have a length measured by an ordinal which is an element of the ordinal which measured the whole line.
Your second question is about why do we associate a well-order with a type if ordinals are supposed to measure the order of the sets elements?
To answer that we need to define what it means for a well-order to have type(X,R) = $\alpha$.
Such an $\alpha$ is the unique ordinal, s.t. there is an isomorphism f:(X,R)≅($\alpha$,$\in$)
By definition, we have that f is a bijection between X and $\alpha$ and we have that for any a,b$\in$X(aRb $\iff$ f(a)$\in$f(b))
It is in this sense, that ordinals give an "order" to the well-ordering.
This property means that the R-least element is associated with $\emptyset$, the second R-least element is associated with 1, and so on.
Therefore, we can associated each element in X with some ordinal which denotes its "order/position" in the well-ordering.
